# How To Use deviceToken in applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, objective-c

Iam able to get and use device token fine here:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

// Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
    NSString *deviceToken = [[[[devToken description]
                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

}
```

I would like to get/use the deviceToken within:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
// How To GET/USE device Token Here?
}
```

Comment: Just Store Device Token in `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store device token in `NSUserDefaults` , so when ever you want it you can easily get it,

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{

    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Now you can get it anywhere anytime till your app is not deleted.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSString *token=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"token"];


}
```

Comment: it is the point that line `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Answer (score 0):

you can add a property in your appDelegate,like this:
[image]

then you can set the property in - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken ,and get the property in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application.

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to convert `deviceToken` into Base64 `NSString`, so you no need to parse description. You can store this value in private member of you AppDelegate (using category), or public property.